# What does "cast to pointer from integer of different size" mean?

Tags: c, pointers

This is an example of what my code looks like:

```
void *a = NULL;
void *b = //something;
a = (void *)(*((char *)b + 4));
```

The value that (b+4) is pointing to is an address that I want to store in a. When I try to compile, I get "warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size." What does this mean, and what should I do to fix it?

EDIT: To clarify, I don't want 'a' to point to an address that is 4 bytes greater than 'b'. In my program, I know that the value stored at ((char *)b + 4) is itself another pointer, and I want to store this pointer in 'a'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `char*`:

```
(char *)b + 4
```

That means that this:

```
*((char *)b + 4)
```

is a `char`. Then you proceed to cast that `char` to a `void*` and the compiler complains. You don't have to manually cast to `void*` in C so just this should do:

```
a = (char *)b + 4;
```

---

**Update for comments**: Sounds like you're after this:

```
a = *(char **)((char *)b + 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Now I understand what I did, but my goal is not for 'a' to point to an address 4 bytes greater than 'b'. In my program, I know that the value stored at ((char *)b +4) is itself another pointer, and I want to store this pointer in 'a'.

Comment: @David: See my update please, I think that's what you're after if I'm understanding you.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I'm assuming (char **) means it's a pointer to a pointer? I'm still pretty new to C, so dealing with pointers is confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like: something is wrong in your pointers.

In this case, re-examine your expression: is that really the *address of a `char`* you're getting?

```
(void *)(*((char *)b + 4));
```

so

```
(char *)b
```

is a pointer to `char`, as is

```
(char *)b+4
```

but then `*((char *)b+4)` is dereferencing `(char *)b+4`, so that's type `char` -- and you're then trying to cast that thing, which is probably 1 byte, into a 4 or 8 byte address.  Ergo, mismatched sizes.

Answer (score 0):

it would improve the readability, if you wrote the statements apart
I did this for you and get:

```
char *c = (char *)b;
char *d = c + 4;
a = (void *)
        (*d); // <- this is c char and you want to cast it to a pointer
```

seems like you wrote an asterisk too much

Answer (score 0):

```
void *a = NULL;
char jig[10]="jigarkumar";
void *b = jig;
printf("b is %p",b);
a = (void *)(((char *)b + 4));
printf("\na is %p",a);
```

problem is here

```
a = (void *)(*((char *)b + 4));
             ^
             |
```

this * fetch the value stored at b+4 address & it is assigned to a which is wrong
   so just remove that & your code will work fine